# FBInstant is not defined

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-instant-games

Sentry is showing that **certain** Facebook users are receiving the error:

```
FBInstant is not defined
```

My HTML file includes scripts like so just after the opening `<body>` tag:

```
<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbinstant.6.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

In app.js, FBInstant.initializeAsync is only called after the entire page has loaded:

```
window.onload = function() {
    FBInstant.initializeAsync().then(function() {
       //Load stuff, etc.
    });
}
```

Is fbinstant.6.2.js not being loaded for some reason? This is working for the vast majority of people. It seems to be mostly Chrome users, with a smaller portion of Firefox users as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should always check if it exists before using it, i had the same problem with the JS SDK of Facebook and found out that those people just installed a browser plugin like Ghostery to disable third party plugins.